# NodeRed parsing tasmota json object

Tags: json, parsing, node-red, tasmota

I'm playing with NodeRed. Esp32 with Tasmota sending mqtt message like following example:

```
{
  "Time": "2021-12-05T20:46:40",
  "MJ_HT_V1391ef1": {
    "mac": "582d34684ef1",
    "Temperature": 22.6,
    "Humidity": 50.9,
    "DewPoint": 11.9,
    "Battery": 100,
    "RSSI": -92
  },
  "MJ_HT_V1385877": {
    "mac": "582d31385557",
    "Temperature": 22,
    "Humidity": 53.3,
    "DewPoint": 12,
    "Battery": 85,
    "RSSI": -86
  }
}
```

Please! How do I get the names MJ_HT_V1391ef1 and MJ_HT_V1385877 without knowing them and also json can have more similar object then only two. Also I will need to get to the information like MJ_HT_V1391ef1.mac or MJ_HT_V1391ef1.Temperature.

If I use something like

```
var zprava=msg.payload;
msg.payload=zprava["MJ_HT_V1391ef1"]["Temperature"];
```

It works and I get a value 22.6. But I need to do it more dynamic. Some loop which  will go through the json?

I spend almost 5 days with finding solution. Please help me.

Comment: flow this to next function node and use javascript to iterate "for(var v in payload) { console.log(v); //MJ_HT_V1391ef1, MJ_HT_V1385877  }". then its javascript skill to manipulate data . payload[v]['mac'], payload[v]['Temperature'] etc

Comment: Why does it have to be dynamic, surely you will need to know the values ahead of time to because you will know which sensors you have deployed where.

Answer (score 1):

JSONata to the rescue! Take a look here:

https://try.jsonata.org/gKcGY7Y2_

So you do `$keys` in a `change` node, then a `split` node, then just check if the key name starts with MJ (again, using JSONata):

`$contains(payload, /^MJ/)`